# "/call is not a valid command" despite it being suggested on slack help centre

Tags: windows, slack

[This is what Slack suggests](https://slack.com/intl/en-cz/help/articles/115003538426-Troubleshoot-Slack-calls) to diagnose issues with calls:

> Type `/call --test` into the search field at the top of the menu.

I followed the instructions, clicked the lightning icon and then the "Send to message input" field:

[image]

When I do that, I get this message:

> **/call** is not a valid command. In Slack, all messages that start with the "/" character are interpreted as commands.
> If you are trying to send a message and not run a command, try preceding the "/" with an empty space.

So what am I doing wrong when running the command? I am running it on Slack for Desktop on Windows 10.

Comment: Did you type it into the search field at the top of the menu, or did you type it into the box where you type messages?

Comment: @user253751 I did it exactly as in the instructions, as per my updated question, and also tried to just type it into the chat field.

Comment: Maybe try the other option? "Search Slack for /call --test"

Comment: @user253751 Not sure why it would be viable option, but I tried it and it didn't show anything apart from ordinary search results.

Answer (score 1):

I noticed that I get the same message when I send the `/call --test` command in a direct message to myself or in a direct message to the Slackbot.

It does work for me if I send the command to another person or in a group channel.